# Invite Only app for Django Auth

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django web app and want to restrict signup to my site. For thatI  want to use invite only app..I could find a couple of app built on the top of Django registration but I'm using Django Auth . Is there any app which I can use with Django app to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is a invite app built on allauth which restricts signup to invite only:

https://pypi.org/project/django-invitations/

Answer (score 1):

General idea:
First, you can check out [the code](http://pastebin.com/sd9p3MwV) I have written which works fine for me.

> Take a look at the example include in the application, you will learn
>   how to write your own pipeline. this pipeline can be redirected to any
>   view you would like.
>
> from there you can save a invitation_key in your sessions and if that
>   key is valid, you can continue with create_user built in pipeline.

I have used [this application](http://code.larlet.fr/django-invitation/wiki/Home) for invitations that produces and validates invitation keys.

[Implementation](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=sd9p3MwV)

It took me quite a day to figure it out.